# function declaration inside main and also outside main in C

Tags: c

The first program compiled properly.second gave error saying too few argument for foo...
is global declaration ignored by the compiler in both programs?

**first program:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
    void foo();
int main()
{
  void foo(int);
  foo(1);
  return 0;
}

void foo(int i)
{
   printf("2 ");
}

void f()
{
   foo(1);
}
```

**second program:**

```
void foo();
int main()
{
  void foo(int);
  foo();
  return 0;
}

void foo()
{
   printf("2 ");
}

void f()
{
   foo();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *inner declaration* hides declarations at the *global scope*. The second program fails because the declaration `void foo(int);` hides the global declaration `void foo();`; so when you say `foo` within `main` you are referring to the one taking an `int` as argument.

Comment: but i want to know how inner declarations work? does compiler just ignore global always? as in f() function if it calls foo() why does it not consider global declaration?

Comment: @user1315833: An _inner declaration_ always _hides_ an _outer declaration_ of the same name, so the compiler cannot even see the outer declaration (as its hidden).

Answer (score 0):

I see that you investigate the specific behavior of inner declaration but why not:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void foo(int);

int main()
{
    foo(1);
    return 0;
}

void foo(int i)
{
   printf("2 ");
}

void f()
{
   foo(1);
}
```

or even:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void foo(int i)
{
   printf("2 ");
}

void f()
{
   foo(1);
}

int main()
{
    foo(1);
    return 0;
}
```